# Can I create an iterator by copying the structure to a list and returning iterator of the list?

Tags: list, iterator, hashtable

If I have a somewhat complex structure (such as hash table with chaining) and I want to create a custom iterator for the structure, is it valid to copy the contents of the complex structure into some sort of simple structure (such as a list) and then return the implicit iterator over the simple structure?
I realize it would take extra memory but are there any other reasons why I shouldn't just do that as opposed to creating my own iterator from a scratch?

Comment: Aren't you going to need to iterate over the elements in your original collection in order to create your copy? Also if you want to edit the elements using the iterator then the copy approach wont work (it would edit the copy)

Comment: @ROX I can use nested for each loops to iterate over the object to copy but not to manually implement hasNext() functions or similar. Editing would be unavailable, that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, yes you can do this if you don't need to edit elements in the original collection via your iterator.

You identify the memory issue; are there other reasons you shouldn't do this? There's the time taken to create the list. You'd either need to recreate this list copy every time you want to iterate or you'd have to make sure you keep the list up-to-date if the original collection can change.

That cost is particularly unfortunate if you wanted to use your iterator to do something like find the first element that meets some rule. If the first element meets the rule but there are a large number of elements then you end up doing a lot of copying in order to eventually only iterate up to the first element.

You can however write your own iterator to do the same job as your nested loops. Its hard to give a decent code example without knowing the structure you're trying to iterate, but in general you're likely to implement it using a class that holds an iterator of elements within a subcollection this is advanced until that current subcollection has been fully iterated and then moves on to the start next subcollection. So your iterator also has an iterator of the collections i.e. 2 iterators - one returns an element and one returns a (sub)collection.

Comment: I never realized I could just have an iterator within an iterator. That makes things much simpler than I thought. I knew there had to be a simpler, cleaner way than just copying a list without creating a complex custom iterator class. Thanks!